# Issue with fixed header background on iPhone's Safari

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari

I am having problems with my fix header on iPhone's Safari. When the window is scrolled down, header gets the class "fixed_header", which also adds a white background to it (original background color is transparent) and change other elements inside to a darker color.

Its working perfectly on Chrome, but in Safari, when I scroll up, the .up class keeps its white background while all elements inside it go back to its original state. I thought it might be related to the fact that safari changes its address bar height when scrolling, and this might delay or confuse the js.

How can I fix it?

```
 $(window).on("load resize", function(){
            var headerTop = $(".header").offset().top;
            var headerHeight = $(".header").outerHeight();
            $(window).on("scroll", function(){
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if(scrollTop > headerTop){
                    $('.header').addClass("fixed_header");
                } else {
                    $('.header').removeClass("fixed_header");
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is the css:

```
.fixed_header {
      background-color: white;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
      @include SP {
        background-color: transparent;
        .up {
          background-color: white;
        }
        h1 {
          opacity: 0;
          position: absolute;
        }
        .logo {
          background-image: url("../images/common/logo_sp_sm_dark.png");
        }
        .contact_btn {
          background-image: url("../images/common/btn_contact_dark.png");
        }
        .menu-trigger span {
          background-color: #1e2328;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding a delay on the background change, that will cover the gap caused by Safari's adress bar resizing.

```
var moven = true;
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 20 && moven == true) {
             $("header").addClass("fixed_header");
        } else {
             $("header").removeClass("fixed_header");
        }
    });
```